# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined, Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, binding

I have the following function with a number of bindings...

```
showDialog: function(data) {
  var dialog = new dialog({
    onOk: function(text) {

      var obj = {
        data: text.data
      };

      this.model.save(obj, {
        method: 'PUT',
        success: function() {
          this.success().bind(this)
        }.bind(this)
      });
    }.bind(this)
  });
  Main.dialogArea.show(dialog);
}
```

Though the code works, it throws the following error in the console...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

The error has to do with the following line `this.success().bind(this)`.

I realized that this gets fixed if I use `var self = this` instead...

```
showDialog: function(data) {
  var self = this;
  var dialog = new dialog({
    onOk: function(text) {

      var obj = {
        data: text.data
      };

      self.model.save(obj, {
        method: 'PUT',
        success: function() {
          self.success()
        }
      });
    }
  });
  Main.dialogArea.show(dialog);
}
```

If I do this, the error disappears. Any idea as to why that is? Shouldn't both cases work the same? I am not using ES6 so I cannot use arrow functions, I would like to use `bind()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

`this.success.bind(this)`

Instead of `this.success().bind(this)`.
Currently you're calling the function, function returns `undefined` and you're invoking `.bind` on it.

Side note:

Since you're doing

```
success: function() {}.bind(this)
```

You shouldn't have to bind a direct method invocation inside it, i.e

```
success: function() {
   this.success();
}.bind(this)
```

Should work, or just

```
success: this.success.bind(this)
```